# .htaccess Mod_Rewrite inconsistent

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Working rules:
RewriteRule ^privacy$              privacy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$                terms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^team$                 team.php [L]
RewriteRule ^candidates$           candidates.php [L]
RewriteRule ^clients$              clients.php [L]

#Not working rules:
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*).*$    article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^job/([^/]*).*$        job.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/([^/]*).*$    contact.php?location=$1 [L]
```

The top rules are all working fine.

**All of the rules were working** in the Beta folder on the client's server, but having moved it across to a live subdirectory those rules are not working.

For example, the second rule in that segment revolves around `job.php`, where:

```
exit(print_r($_GET));
```

outputs:

```
Array ( ) 1
```

which shows that the `$_GET` variables are not passing through via `mod_rewrite`.

I understand that `.htaccess` changes take place immediately so why are these rules not working?

Comment: I see you rewrite every php file to a version without .php extension why don't you rewrite all php files to a version without .php http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#Working rules:
RewriteRule ^privacy$              privacy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$                terms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^team$                 team.php [L]
RewriteRule ^candidates$           candidates.php [L]
RewriteRule ^clients$              clients.php [L]

RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/?$    article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^job/([^/]+)/?$        job.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/([^/]+)/?$    contact.php?location=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.